Error in creating odoo user
useradd -m -U -r -d /opt/odoo17 -s /bin/bash odoo17
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

I got this error while typing useradd -m -U -r -d /opt/odoo17 -s /bin/bash odoo17
why?
How to solve?
